# Getting the intersection of a line and a plain

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

My line `(2,1,10)` goes through the plain with the normal `(-2,3,8)`.

Now I would like to calculate the intersection with following formula
[image]

The resulting equation system supposed to be

[image]

Which I don't understand. How is `(0,1,10)` on the right side of the equation?

Comment: This is just $$(2,1,10)-(2,0,0).$$

Answer (score 2):

I think you gave a wrong hypothesis: the line passes by the point $(2,1,10)$ and parallel to the vector $(2,-3,8)^T$ and the plane passes by the point $(2,0,0)$ and parallel to the plane spanned by the vectors $(2,4,1)^T$ and $(-1,2,1)^T$. From this hypothesis we get the given system of equations.